# Are these quotes from a book by Richard von Coudenhove-Kalergi?

Tags: quotes

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hw5u883ypg4) claims to quote various writings of Richard Kalergi. It says that the following quote is from his book:

> The Jewish prophets of the present are preparing a new world era, in particular to make the ethical primary: in politics, religion, philosophy and art

I have search for the quote with the following two search strings in google. The first one didn't give any hits and the second one primarily refers to anti Semitic sites that either want Jews expelled from the west or genocided with Zyklon B gas.

1. "particular to make the ethical primary"
2. "the jewish prophet of the present"

The video claims the following quote is from his book practical idealism:

> "The man of the future will be a mongrel. Today's races and classes will disappear, owing to the disappearing of space, time and prejudice.
>
> The Eurasian-Negroid race of the future.. will replace the diversity of people with diversity of individuals."

Are these quotes from Richard von Coudenhove-Kalergi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coudenhove-Kalergi wrote [Praktischer Idealismus](https://archive.org/details/PraktischerIdealismus1925) which says:

> Der Mensch der fernen Zukunft wird Mischling sein. Die heutigen Rassen und Kasten werden der zunehmen- [page 22] den Überwindung von Raum, Zeit und Vorurteil zum Opfer fallen. Die eurasisch-negroide 
>   Zukunftsrasse, äußerlich der altägyptischen ähnlich, wird die Vielfalt der Völker durch eine 
>   Vielfalt der Persönlichkeiten ersetzen. Denn nach den Vererbungsgesetzen wächst mit der 
>   Verschiedenheit der Vorfahren die Verschiedenheit, mit der Einförmigkeit der Vorfahren die 
>   Einförmigkeit der Nachkommen. In Inzuchtfamilien gleicht ein Kind dem anderen: denn alle 
>   repräsentieren den einen gemeinsamen Familientypus. In Mischlingsfamilien unterscheiden sich 
>   die Kinder stärker voneinander: jedes bildet eine neuartige Variation der divergierenden 
>   elterlichen und vorelterlichen Elemente.

or roughly translated (German speakers please help improve):

> The man of the distant future will be a hybrid. Today's races and castes will fall victim to the overcoming of space, time, and prejudice.  The Eurasian-Negroid hybrid race, similar to ancient Egyptian, will replace the diversity of peoples with a variety of personalities.  For according to hereditary laws, the diversity of the ancestors increases diversity, and the uniformity of the ancestors, the uniformity of the offspring.  In inbreeding families one child resembles the other: for all represent the one family type. In mixed-bodied families the children are more different from each other: each represents a new variation of the diverging parental and pre-parental elements.

additionally, around page 27 depending on how you count the pages, it says:

> Diesen jüdischen Propheten der Gegenwart, die eine neue Weltepoche vorbereiten, ist in allem 
>   das Ethische Primär: in Politik, Religion, Philosophie und Kunst. Von Moses bis Weininger war 
>   Ethik Hauptproblem jüdischer Philosophie. In dieser ethischen Grundeinstellung zur Welt liegt 
>   eine Wurzel der einzigartigen Größe des jüdischen Volkes - zugleich aber die Gefahr, daß Juden, 
>   die ihren Glauben an die Ethik verlieren, zu zynischen Egoisten herabsinken: während Menschen 
>   anderer Mentalität auch nach Verlust ihrer ethischen Einstellung noch eine Fülle ritterlicher 
>   Werte und Vorurteile (Ehrenmann, Gentleman, Kavalier usw.) übrigbehalten, die sie vor dem 
>   Sturz in das Werte-Chaos schützen.

or roughly translated:

> To these Jewish prophets of the present, who are preparing a new world epoch, the ethical is primary in everything: in politics, religion, philosophy, and art.  From Moses to Weininger, ethics was the main problem of Jewish philosophy. In this basic ethical attitude to the world lies a root of the unique greatness of the Jewish people - but at the same time the danger that Jews who lose their faith in ethics will sink to cynical egoists: while people of other mentality, even after losing their ethical attitude, still have an abundance Chivalrous values ​​and prejudices (honorsman, gentleman, cavalier, etc.) who protect them from the fall into the chaos of values.

Answer (score 3):

**I found this book with the title "Practical Idealism" but it is not by Kalergi.**

Wikipedia's article on Richard von Coudenhove-Kalergi lists *Praktischer Idealismus* (1925) among his [Publications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_von_Coudenhove-Kalergi#Publications).

The [Views on race and religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_von_Coudenhove-Kalergi#Views_on_race_and_religion) section make it plausible that he would have been writing about topics such as this this. The section starts with,

> In his attitudes towards race and religion, Coudenhove-Kalergi continued the work of his father. In his youth, the elder Coudenhove-Kalergi was an antisemite. He had expected to confirm his antipathy towards the Jews when he started working on his treatise *Das Wesen des Antisemitismus* (The Essence of Antisemitism); but, Coudenhove-Kalergi came to a different conclusion by the time he published his book in 1901. Following an ironic critique of the new racial theories, he declared that [etc.]

I don't (currently) read German so I won't pursue this search, but a/the place to look would be in *Praktischer Idealismus* (1925).

---

You wrote,

> I have search for the quote with the following two search strings in google. The first one didn't give any hits and the second one primarily refers to anti Semitic sites ...

I too find sites, [like this](http://balder.org/judea/Richard-Coudenhove-Kalergi-Practical-Idealism-Vienna-1925.php) which publishes translations such as "Europeans to become negroid mongrels" ... IMO to get a more authoritative source than that (and this site normally requires that an answer be mre authoritative than the sources you are questioning in the OP), an answer might need to read and reference *Praktischer Idealismus* in the original German.

---

I'm guessing that they probably *are* quotes (but that sites which quote them *may* be quoting them out of context, and/or giving tendentious translations).